# jQuery/Javascript: How to get anonymous function to reference variable declare outside?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some jQuery code that doesn't work as expected.

```
$('a[href^="http://"]').not('[href^="http://mydomain.com"], [href^="http://itunes.apple.com"]').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("external: " + this.getAttribute('href'));
    var url = this.getAttribute('href');
    foo.track(
        "External", 
        { 'URL': url }, 
        function (url) { 
            location.href = url 
        }
    );
});
```

For this example, I'm tracking all external clicks from my domain, except for iTunes apps store.  Assume `foo.track()` is a 3rd party method I'm using to track some events for reporting. The last parameter to it is an anonymous function that is executed once the tracking call successfully returns.

The code above is trying to navigate everything to `http://mydomain.com/1` for some reason. However, the `console.log` statement succesfully logs the expected values.  It's as if the `url` variable isn't referencing the value I expect.  I've also tried replacing `location.href = url` with `window.location = url` but I get the same result.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Personally, I think you'd be MUCH better off doing this on the server side than client side.

Comment: You've declared "url" as a parameter to that anonymous function.  What do you see when you do the `console.log()` from **inside** that function?

Comment: As a side comment, I recommend event delegation for this. You don't want to explicitly bind to *all* your external links.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas: What is "event delegation"?

Comment: @TMC Instead of binding the event handler to every anchor, with event delegation you bind it to a common ancestor element (in this case you can bind it to the BODY element). Then, inside the even handler, you use the `event.target` reference to determine which anchor (if any) was clicked. You can do this because events bubble up the DOM tree, so if you click an anchor, the "click" event will fire at the BODY element also. There are plenty of articles on the internet. Google "jquery event delegation".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the parameter from the navigation function. Like this:

```
$('a[href^="http://"]').not('[href^="http://mydomain.com"], 
                             [href^="http://itunes.apple.com"]').click(function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
console.log("external: " + this.getAttribute('href'));
var url = this.getAttribute('href');
foo.track("External", { 'URL': url }, function (/*url*/) { location.href = url });
});
```

Comment: That's probably it. The `foo.track()` function probably passes `'http://mydomain.com/1'` to the function call for some reason...